# How do I test that proximity sensor on Galaxy Nexus works as expected

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, proximity-sensor

I've noticed two days ago that I've initiated some random things while having hands in my pockets and phone was in as well...

And today I just picked up a call and while talking on the phone I realised that I turned on stuff with my face...

It seems that proximity sensor isn't working or working improperly.

How do I test it without placing a call?
How can I test proximity sensor anyway?
Is it at all possible?

I've read about some proximity sensor light... I don't see any light turning on or anything... I can just locate two *holes* behind glass between front camera and speaker. I suppose one of them (or both) is proximity sensor.

> Galaxy Nexus is 2 weeks old and running Jelly Bean

Comment: The proximity sensor uses no light, the two holes you mention are the proximity sensor and the ambient light sensor, which measures the lighting around the phone and uses it to adjust automatic display brightness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install a sensor app like [AndroSens](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tritop.android.androsens) or [AndroSensor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fivasim.androsensor).

They both are able to show you the proximity information.

Note:
The sensor only distinguishes between near and far proximity (0-5cm and >=5cm usually). It is OK that you won't get accurate distance measurements.

Answer (score 2):

Many android phones have a hidden app called **"service menu"** which runs when you call some codes in Phone app.

for example, service menu for Sony (Ericsson) android phones will appear when you call `*#*#7378423#*#*` or `*#*#SERVICE#*#*` and for most of samsung android phones, it appears when you call `*#0*#` or `*#9072641*#`

from "service menu", you can test Screen, Keys, Touch, ... and most importantly, **sensors**. So, test this code in your phone and see if "service menu" appears, then test your **proximity sensor** from there, without any need to install a third-party app.